# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Begin'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a hotel project and I need to check the availability of rooms. Here the logic is first need to check the room availability if it is not available then I need to check if checkout date entered by the customer is equal to the checkout date of any customer:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[customerdetails] (@CheckIn     DATE, ...)
AS
  BEGIN
      BEGIN TRY
          IF ( (SELECT Available
                FROM   rooms
                WHERE  roomtype = @RoomType) > 0 )
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO Customerdetail
                VALUES      (@CheckIn, ...)
            END
          ELSE IF(SELECT *
             FROM   Customerdetail
             WHERE  RoomType = @RoomType
                    AND CheckOut = @CheckOut)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO Customerdetail
                VALUES     (@CheckIn, ...)
            END
      END TRY

      BEGIN CATCH
          DECLARE @ErrMessage NVARCHAR(max)

          SET @ErrMessage=ERROR_MESSAGE()

          RAISERROR (@ErrMessage,16,1)
      END CATCH
  END
```

But I get an error:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1
>   
> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'BEGIN'.

Comment: You need to use COUNT - `IF ((Select COUNT(Available) FROM ROOMS WHERE roomtype=@RoomType) > 0)`

Comment: @Tim - `EXISTS` could be better.

Comment: @MartinSmith - True, it would be.  'Twas a drive by comment as I'm out the door :)

Comment: @user2765331 Also have you considered the possibility of concurrency?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is actually here, where you just say `IF (get result)`:

```
ELSE IF(SELECT *
             FROM   Customerdetail
             WHERE  RoomType = @RoomType
                    AND CheckOut = @CheckOut)
```

This should be, I think, either `IF (get result) = something` or `IF something (about result)`, e.g.:

```
ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT *
             FROM   Customerdetail
             WHERE  RoomType = @RoomType
                    AND CheckOut = @CheckOut)
```

Also Paul is correct that this clause is not proper:

```
IF ( (SELECT Available
            FROM   rooms
            WHERE  roomtype = @RoomType) > 0 )
```

As written, if more than one row is returned, it will yield:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

So, you should code this using `EXISTS` as he suggested.

You should also make sure you test this solution under a high level of concurrency, as Martin suggested in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
IF ( (SELECT Available
            FROM   rooms
            WHERE  roomtype = @RoomType) > 0 )
```

to:

```
IF ( exists(SELECT Available
            FROM   rooms
            WHERE  roomtype = @RoomType) )
```

Comment: While I agree this is better, this won't actually resolve the error, as it is happening in the other branch.